# Angular 2 on click table cell make it editable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a ngFor for rows and I what when i click on some cell to make it editable

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceItem.rows">
    <td contenteditable='true' (input)="onRowClick($event, invoice.rowId)">{{ invoice.rowName }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.hours}}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.comments }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.total}} </td>


</tr>
```

more over I what to support it with new rows added

```
<button (click)='addRow()'>Add a row</button>



 addRow() {
        this.invoiceItem.rows.push({
            invoiceDetailsId: this.invoiceItem.item.invoiceId,
            rowName: '',
            hours: 0,
            price: 0,
            comments: '',
            total: 0,
            rowId: 
        }) 
    }
    onRowClick(event, id) {
        console.log(event.target.outerText, id);
    }
```

what should i implement for this task?

Comment: Hey! I don't know if you get notified when I undeleted answer. But check, there is a working solution. Not so pretty, but at least it works ;)

Comment: ok checking , tnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one solution that works. It might not be pretty, but it works.

Change your table structure to something like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceItem.rows">
    <td *ngIf="invoice.rowId == editRowId"> 
       <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="invoice.hours">
    </td>
    <td *ngIf="invoice.rowId !== editRowId" (click)="toggle(invoice.rowId)">
       {{invoice.rowId}}
    </td>
    <!-- the rest of your fields in same manner -->
</tr>
```

And in your component:

```
editRowId: any;

toggle(id){
  this.editRowId = id;
}
```

This also supports the adding of a new row. I have come up with a hack for setting the id for the new row, like so:

```
addRow() {
  let indexForId = this.invoiceItem.rows.length + 1
  this.rows.push({
    // .....
    rowId: indexForId,
  })
}
```

You might find a better way :)

Here's a working **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/271eKUIUvdkKOHi0SaAd)**

Comment: As a comment, you've probably found this one as well, if you are willing to use... https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-editable-table

Answer (score 0):

ok, first you will add 1 more property for each `invoice` called `editable: false`, then when looping through list, you'll binding data like this;

```
[contenteditable]="invoice.editable"
```

do this for all `td`

```
<td (input)="onRowClick($event, invoice.rowId)">
    <div [contenteditable]="invoice.editable ? 'true': 'false'">{{ invoice.rowName }}</div>
</td>
```

Comment: i didnt get it @Tiep Phan, i add what you saud to rows but get an error

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'contenteditable' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. ("
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceItem.rows">
<td [ERROR ->][contenteditable]="invoice.editable" (click)="invoice.editable = !invoice.editable">{{ invoice.rowNam"): DemoTestComponent@34:16
Can't bind to 'contenteditable' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. ("ditable" (click)="invoice.editable = !invoice.editable">{{ invoice.rowName }}</td>

Comment: Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'contenteditable' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("let invoice of invoiceItem.rows">
<td (input)="onRowClick($event, invoice.rowId)"><div [ERROR ->][contenteditable]="invoice.editable ? 'true': 'false'">{{ invoice.rowName }}</div></td>
"): DemoTestComponent@34:65

Comment: it's seem Angular limit this feature, you could create your own directive to binding into this property, or try `contenteditable="{{ invoice.editable ? 'true': 'false'}}"`